# Moving stripe which keeps changing value

Tags: javascript, php, flash

I need to create moving stripe(I don't know how to name it) on my website. Something like this:

```
|--@---------|
```

And the @ can be moved by the user from one side to another and when the bar is clicked it sends the value but it can't be done with manual requests so the user chooses the value to send. I just need some tips how I can do this. I think it can be done by flash but I don't even know what should I internet search keywords should be used to find more info about it.

Comment: You mean a range input? ```<input type="range">```

Comment: Flash is not fully supported in modern browsers anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As Wainage suggested, an [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) with type [*range*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range) is perhaps a simple solution. See an example below.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var slider = document.getElementById('rangeValue');
    var output = document.getElementById('valueOutput');

    function updateOutput() {
      output.innerHTML = slider.value;
    }

    //set the value initially
    updateOutput();

    //subscribe to any change/drag - not supported by IE
    slider.addEventListener('input', updateOutput);

    //use change event for updates when drag is ended
    slider.addEventListener('change', updateOutput);
});
```

```html
<input id="rangeValue" type="range" name="rangeValue" value="3" max="10" />
<div>Value: <span id="valueOutput"></span></div>
```